# How to call WCF service from .NET 1.1

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-1.1

I have a WCF service which I'm trying to call from a simple .NET 1.1 client. The problem I'm having relates to the sending of "Client Credentials" to the service. In .NET 3.5 I can add the following lines so that the username and password are sent in the message (SOAP) header:

```
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "USERNAME";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PASSWORD";
```

How can I replicate this functionality using .NET 1.1?

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot - WCF is a .NET 3.0 and up technology.

All you can do from .NET 1.1 is to call

- WCF services with `basicHttpBinding` (and basically no security)
- WCF REST services (`webHttpBinding`) through the browser/http stack

Comment: For the "basicHttpBinding" option - does that imply that in terms of security I would need to add the username and password as parameters if I needed some type of security? - Thanks

Comment: @josepv: from .NET 1.1, you cannot really call WCF - but you can call a WCF service with basicHttpBinding that "pretends" to be a ASMX web service. In that case, however, there is no security other than possibly transport security (HTTPS protocol with SSL certificates)